# Как выровнить отступы между картинок чтобы они встали ровно при display: flex;

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
  .section__photo {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap; 
    padding-bottom: 73px;
width: 1280px;

}
  

.section__photo-gallery{
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;

}

.section__photo-gallery:last-child(3n - 1){
margin-right: 0;

}






.section__content{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
opacity: 0;


}

.section__content:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="section__photo">
    <div class="section__photo-gallery">
    <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-1.jpg"  alt="" >
  <div class="section__content"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="section__photo-gallery">
    <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-2.jpg"  alt="" >
    <div class="section__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="section__photo-gallery">
    <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-3.jpg"  alt="" >
    <div class="section__content"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="section__photo-gallery">
     <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-4.jpg"  alt="" >
     <div class="section__content"></div>
  </div>
    

  <div class="section__photo-gallery">
     <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-5.jpg" alt="" >
     <div class="section__content"></div>
    </div>

   
    <div class="section__photo-gallery">
    <img class="photo__gallery" src="image/photo__bg-6.jpg" alt="" >
      <div class="section__content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[image: То что получается!Как должно быть]

Comment: если кратко то никак в таком случае. мое предложение добавлять класы широким дивам и делать их flex: 0 0 50%; а маленьким по 25. или через nth-child каждому нужному делать ширину 50%. по поводу высоты другой вопрос.

Comment: Лучше используйте более подходящий для этого лайаут - grid.

Comment: Я так почему то подумал, а если у меня верстка на флексах то заново все переделывать

Comment: Если не хотите проблем с вычислениями процентов для каждого размера картинок, то однозначно - grid вместо flex.